# How to align inner text in div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the text inside a div in center of the page and also text start from left side. But getting a problem as role1, role2 text is showing in center of Role(r) text i want that all the text should right aligned but in center of the page.

```css
.home-role-access-text {
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -125px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #026890;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-role-access-text" data-ng-show="alarmsCounter <= 0">
  <div>
    <div data-ng-hide="assignedRoles.length<=0">
      <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;"><b>Role(r)</div>
           
            <div style="font-size:11px;font-weight: 100;display: inline-block; text-align: left" data-ng-repeat="role in  assignedRoles">Role1 </div>
        <div style="font-size:11px;font-weight: 100;display: inline-block; text-align: left" data-ng-repeat="role in  assignedRoles">Role3 </div>

        </div>
    </div>
         
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: you should use a `p` inside de div

Comment: Can you show me where i need to use <p>

Comment: Can you add a image showing how you want ?

Comment: I have added a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `display` in the child divs of `<div class="roles">`  to `block` instead of `inline-block`.

I have included a jsfiddle as well. I had to change the CSS for `.home-role-access-text`to get all text to start on the left and stay within it's container. I suggest using `display: flex` because it's better at centering a block of content. https://jsfiddle.net/Luxz8eff/

```
.home-role-access-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #026890;
}

<div class="home-role-access-text" data-ng-show="alarmsCounter <= 0">
  <div>
    <div data-ng-hide="assignedRoles.length<=0">
      <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;"><b>Role(r)</b></div>

  <div style="font-size:11px;font-weight: 100;display: block; text-align: left" data-ng-repeat="role in  assignedRoles">Role1 </div>
  <div style="font-size:11px;font-weight: 100;display: block; text-align: left" data-ng-repeat="role in  assignedRoles">Role3 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Going by your image it seems you want all text left aligned inside a div that is right aligned of the center.

Based on that, you can float the container right with all text aligned left.

```css
.home-role-access-text {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -125px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #026890;
}

.roles {
float:right
}
```

```html
<div class="home-role-access-text" data-ng-show="alarmsCounter <= 0">
  <div>
    <div data-ng-hide="assignedRoles.length<=0" class="roles">
      <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;"><b>Role(r)</b></div>
          <div style="font-size:11px;font-weight: 100;display: block; text-align: left;" data-ng-repeat="role in  assignedRoles">Role1 </div>
          <div style="font-size:11px;font-weight: 100;display: block; text-align: left;" data-ng-repeat="role in  assignedRoles">Role3 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The black border in the example is only added to show the div is still centered with right aligned text - You can off course, remove it :)

Comment: Well this is not what i am looking for, i have added a picture what i want to look like this. please check my post

Comment: Sorry, I can't see images where I'm images get blocked. I'm only able to go by your explanation.

Comment: @user526206 You said you wanted the text to be right aligned in the center of the page so that's what you get.

Comment: @user526206 If you also want the `Role(r)` text right aligned then use the existing container...I update the code.

Comment: @user526206 I checked the image on my mobile phone and going by that you don't seem to want all text right aligned as your question implied but left aligned within a container aligned to the right of the center. I updated my answer and think it does that now. - Ignore the black border, that is only to show that your main container still is centered.